# Send SMS on Android to itself

Tags: android, sms

I need to write a service that translate short messages obtain from JSON and transform it to a SMS.  Is it possible for an Android service to send itself SMS?  If so, which lib or api?

(In some way, fake SMS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you have to get an SMS in the inbox is to send a regular message to the own phone number (you may incur in two sms charges, so be careful on how you use it).